# Visual Studio 2017 won't show anything in stack trace and than crushes my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I've been working on xamarin to build a crossplatform project on VS2017. I'm in the late phases of development and everything used to work fine. Couple of days ago while coding, I took a brake and updated windows. Since than my visual studio has gone **"crazy"** . Every time I deploy an application on a device and trying to debug it, it will only show a message in the stack trace and then it will crash my app. 
This is what it shows :

> Android application is debugging.

In this moment the app will reopen and than crush. It's a very strange behaviour. I of course tried different apps which used to perfectly work, and they have the same issue. I even tried it with a brand new application. Same thing. And of course the app works when I build it from my windows PC to an Iphone or iphone simulator. I can't wrap my head around this.

Has this happened to anybody lately? Is there a problem with the PC or a problem with the VS2017 ???
A little help would be very appreciated. :)

== edit ==

My VS2017 version is : 15.4.2 . Is there any known problem with this kind of version??

Answer (score 0):

try to enable Exceptions 
Debug > Windows > Exception Settings

Comment: It says : `Android application is debugging.
This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.
` 
What does this mean? Any idea? @martina

Comment: @John do you start the debugger clicking on button Debug?

Comment: Yes @martina that's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can be a problem of the emulator. In short, get a fresh installed copy of the .android folder by installing vs on other pc, delete the current one, RESTART your PC and paste the copy to its folder. 
To makr things more clear, I believe its good to share my attempts.  What I noticed from my experience is, the emulators start behaving odd on your normal debug process. The reasons can be different, some of which were, according to my experience, sudden pc shut down, using large file size images as drawable backgrounds, closing emulator before debug was complete and so on.
Once such odd behavior happened to the emulator, I tried everything I could access online to reset the emulator or create a new one but none solved my problem, even reinstalling vs2017. Finally I was left with one choice which I still think is a foolish idea. Backed up and reinstalled windows, reinstalled VS2017 and other software I needed at that moment. When I was done with clean installation, before I started my work, I copied and backed up the .android folder (almost 10GB for the four default installed emulators) that is located in the user folder and continued my work as usual. And if the emulator fails again at anytime (like even in cases of black screen, being super SLOW, Launcher not responding...), I DELETE the current .android folder in the current user folder, make sure all of the emulators ARE NOT available for the debug option (replaced by **start**) in visual studio, RESTART the pc (important), copy your backed up .android folder and paste it back to your user folder where it was originally located.
Then you are good to go. I hope this will help someone.